# DevExpress XtraTreeList set focused Row Appearance to only show background color change

Tags: devexpress, xtratreelist

Is there a way to set a selected/focused Row Appearance so that it makes the row only bordered (no background color changes, border color red) ?

Answer (score 3):

Click the smart tag button on the top right of the control when it is selected and choose Run Designer.

[image: Smart Tag]

Then under the appearances tab on the left you can specifically set the color of most of the components in the control

[image: Appearances]

Answer (score 2):

For me FocusedRow/SelectedRow is not working, but it is possible to get the desired result with FocusedCell 
(in treelist designer -> Appearance tab, and then select FocusedCell from Appearances list)

**EDIT**

Both FocusedRow and FocusedCell appearances are enabled by default, so if You have a treelist with one visible column, You will not (as I didn't) see the effect of settings for FocusedRow. In this case You have to disable FocusedCell appearance (or just configure necessary appearance at FocusedCell, not FocusedRow)

```
XtraTreelist.OptionsSelection.EnableAppearanceFocusedCell = false;
```

P.S. I am using DevExpress 13.2.5 version